# Why is this function returning value "undefined" when called in another function?

Tags: jquery, function, variables, undefined

Following problem: I have this function to find the id of my current slide (current slide has a higher `z-index`):

```
function current_slide() {
    var current_slide;
    $('.bxslider').find('li').each(function () {     
        if ($(this).css('z-index') == 50) {               
            current_slide = $(this).prop('class');                
        }
    });        
    return current_slide;
}
```

When i call it like this it returns the correct value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var test = current_slide();
   console.log(test);
});
```

But I need the variable in another function. The other function is this:

```
function pagination() {
    var current = current_slide();
    console.log(current);
    ...
}
```

In my script there is the document.ready function where the pagination function is fired:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   pagination();
});
```

But now the variable current is undefined. Why?

Comment: can you add a console logging within the if loop to check whether it is getting satisfied

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's your problem, but having a variable named the same as a function is going to lead to issues, or at the very least some confusion. I'd highly suggest renaming one of them.

Comment: There are few cases here: **1).** rename your variable `current_slide` to some other name. **2).** `$('.bxslider').find('li')`  couldn't find `li` element. **3).** `if` statement could be always false. Thus `var current_slide; alert(current_slide)` will return `undefined`

Comment: Since he's declaring the variable with "var", it will not affect the function because the variable is not in the same scope (the global scope). But, I agree it will lead to missunderstandings.

Comment: to Arun P Johny and Pavlo: The current_slide function works perfect; to Rory McCrossan: I renamed it but that wasn't the problem. I tried to shorten my endless code here but in the real script wasn't a document.ready when the pagination function is fired the first time... Sorry!